# InlineEdit for OutputField

Tags: apex, visualforce, inlineeditsupport, outputtext, outputfield

I have written this code. I am trying to make the outputText inline editable.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}" rendered="{!!(pA.AcceptedDate__c==NUll&&pA.SentDate__c!=Null)}">
                        <apex:param value="{!pA.AcceptedDate__c}" />     
                    </apex:outputText>
```

However InlineEdit tag can only be used with outputField tag. Now if I change this outputText tag to outputField it is giving me the following error 
**value for `<apex:outputField>` is not a dynamic binding!** 
It is extremely urgent and any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code? It should work if you implemented this way. http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-use-Inline-Edit-in-a-custom-Visualforce-UI-Page-2278.php

Comment: <apex:commandLink onclick="viewInviteAcceptDisclaimer('{!pubAut.id}'); return false;" rendered="{!(pubAut.AcceptedDate__c==NUll&&pubAut.SentDate__c!=Null)}" value="{!if((pubAut.AcceptedDate__c==NUll&&pubAut.SentDate__c!=Null),'Accept',pubAut.AcceptedDate__c)}" id="theCommandLink" />
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}" rendered="{!!(pubAut.AcceptedDate__c==NUll&&pubAut.InviteSentDate__c!=Null)}">
                        <apex:param value="{!pubAut.AcceptedDate__c}" /> 
                    </apex:outputText>   This is the code snippet @susanoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a Visualforce Page and wrote some custom logic to Mimic the Inline Editing functionality for `<apex:outputText`. Not a 100% match though, but to some extent a decent one. Hope this helps.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="InlineEditingHelper">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title= "outputcomponents">
        <apex:outputPanel id="editfield">
            <apex:outputlabel value="Account Name (Double Click To Edit)   :  " for="Accname">
                <apex:actionSupport event="ondblclick" action="{!inlineEdit}" rerender="editfield"/>
            </apex:outputlabel>         
            <apex:outputText label="" value="{!Account.Name}" rendered="{!NOT(editmode)}" id="Accname"/>
            <apex:inputText label="" value="{!Account.Name}" rendered="{!editmode}" id="Accname2"/> 
        </apex:outputPanel>      
    </apex:pageBlock >
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Extension**

```
public with sharing class InlineEditingHelper {
    public boolean editmode {get;set;}
    public InlineEditingHelper(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        editmode = false;
    }
    public void inlineEdit() {
        system.debug('entered here');
        editmode = true;
    }
}
```